# Create a new Planner with Microsoft Flow

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-planner

Using Flow I am trying to create a Team and then a Planner to add to the Team as a Tab.

I'm trying to create a new Planner in Flow with the Group ID generated from creating a Team.

Following [the MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0) I've tried using an HTTP in Flow to make a POST to

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans`

with body

```
{
  "owner": "GROUP ID HERE",
  "title": "Planner"
}
```

But I get an error of **Unauthorised**. Can anyone please advise what I'm doing wrong?

Below is what my permissions on Azure Active Directory looks like to authenticate my API calls:

[image: AzureAD IMAGE]

---

**While I can create a planner through the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)**:

[image: Graph API IMAGE]

Request ID
[image: Response header]

Timestamp
[image: response body]

---

**I can't do the same thing on Flow using HTTP**:

[image: Error IMAGE]
[image: Error IMAGE2]
[image: Error IMAGE3]

Comment: Could you please check if your bearer token has required permission using https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Not sure how I do this. From my knowledge the token _is_ a valid jwt because I've been able to run other API calls (such as cloning Teams) which have worked successfully.

Comment: Could you please confirm that you are member of the group and share the request id and timestamp for failed request as suggested by @Tarkan Sevilmis?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT, I am the owner and a member of the Team and Group. The Flow HTTP doesn't give me a request ID for the failed request. Just 'Unauthorized' as shown above.

Comment: See screenshots above. HTTP 3 is from the POST request for creating a Plan using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans`

Comment: Could you please Share screenshot of HTTP3 Post request with headers and body? Also, if it's possible to try API call in Fiddler or Postman to get request Id and Timestamp which @Tarkan asked?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT see request id and timestamp screenshot above.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT also see a related issue if you think you can help I'd really appreciate it. [MICROSOFT: Adding a Tab to a Team Channel through Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323583/microsoft-adding-a-tab-to-a-team-channel-through-flow)

Comment: I could see request id for successful request in screenshot. We need request id for failed one.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Please tell me how I can get HTTP fail request ID and timestamp from Flow. That is the only place it fails.

Comment: Could you please try sending the same request from fiddle or postman?

Answer (score 0):

Almost every time, the issue with not having authorization to create a plan in a newly created group is because the calling user is not a member in the group. By default, when a group is created, the creator is an owner, but not a member. You'll need to add the user to the members.

If this isn't addressing your issue, you'll need to provide a bit more information on the error. The request id and the timestamp from the failed requests would allow us to directly diagnose the problem.