# Adding a Tab to a Team Channel through Flow

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I'm trying to use Flow to add a SharePoint List Tab to a Channel in a Team. But while I can add a Tab, the Tab is always blank.

I've tried both Microsoft Graph Explorer and Flow but I can't seem to configure the tab to show my SharePoint List. Or any other app for that measure. The tab is always blank.

I've followed the POST from the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-1.0#request)

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/tabs
```

Body:
*NOTE: 2a527703-1f6f-4559-a332-d8a7d288cd88 is the TeamsAppsId for Sharepoint and Lists which I gathered from the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#sharepoint-page-and-list-tabs)*

```
{
  "displayName": "My Contoso Tab",
  "teamsApp@odata.bind" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/2a527703-1f6f-4559-a332-d8a7d288cd88",
  "configuration": {
    "entityId": "LIST ID HERE",
    "contentUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/LIST ID HERE/tabView",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/LIST ID HERE",
    "removeUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/LIST ID HERE/uninstallTab"
  }
}
```

I get a `201 Created` but when I go to my Team and check the Tab in the Channel, its blank and I need to manually set it up from Settings.

When I run the call on explorer using Sharepoint Website AppId (com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web) I get the following success [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrJrZ.png)

But when I go to the Teams List Tab I just created [I see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFWrf.png)

Any suggestions on how I can tackle this?

Comment: [Configuration is not supported for SharePoint page and list tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#sharepoint-page-and-list-tabs). If you want to configure the tab, consider using a Website tab.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT see the edit. I get an error if I use the AppId of a Website for my tab.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? Attempting to do the same.